# Количество лифтов в зависимости от этажности

Tags: excel, excel-формулы

Формула должна расчитывать кол-во лифтов в доме, в зависимости от этажей.
От 6 до 10 этажей – 1 лифт, от 11 до 18 этажей – 2 лифта, от 19 до 30 этажей – 4 лифта.

Она правильно высчитывает от 6 до 10 (показывает 1), но если вводить дальше, то значение всё так же остаётся 1.

Формула:

`=ЕСЛИ(A2>=6;1;ЕСЛИ(И(A2>=11;A2<18);2;ЕСЛИ(И(A2>=19;A2<=30);4;0)))`

Таблица:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `=ЕСЛИ(A2>30;"нельзя больше 30 этажей";ЕСЛИ(A2>=19;4;ЕСЛИ(A2>=11;2;ЕСЛИ(A2>=6;1;0))))`

Comment: @Tunker Большое спасибо, всё работает

Comment: `=ЕСЛИ(A2>30;"перебор";ВПР(A2;{0;0:6;1:11;2:19;3};2))`